# JS AutoComplete Facebook Style (TextboxList) - control the cursor location

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete, mootools

I'm trying to edit [TextboxList](http://www.devthought.com/2008/01/12/textboxlist-meets-autocompletion/) JS plugin to support RTL language (played a bit with its css below). Now, seems like **the cursor is running away after I type every word** - how can I set the cursor to appear exactly after the term I've printed[image]

```
/* TextboxList sample CSS */
ul.holder {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 1%;
    padding: 4px 5px 0;
}

*:first-child+html ul.holder {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

* html ul.holder {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
} /* ie7 and below */
ul.holder li {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 5px 4px 0;
}

ul.holder li.bit-box, ul.holder li.bit-input input {
    font: 11px "Lucida Grande", "Verdana";
}

ul.holder li.bit-box {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #CAD8F3;
    background: #DEE7F8;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px;
}

ul.holder li.bit-box-focus {
    border-color: #598BEC;
    background: #598BEC;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.holder li.bit-input input {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 3px 0 2px;
} /* no left/right padding here please */
ul.holder li.bit-input input.smallinput {
    width: 20px;
}

/* Facebook demo CSS */      
form, #add {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 550px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 20px 30px 10px;
}

form ol {
    font: 11px "Lucida Grande", "Verdana";
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

form ol li.input-text {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

form ol li.input-text label {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form ol li.input-text input {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 5px 5px 6px;
    font: 11px "Lucida Grande", "Verdana";
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

form ul.holder {
    width: 500px;
}

#facebook-list ul.holder li.bit-box, #apple-list ul.holder li.bit-box {
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

#apple-list ul.holder li.bit-input {
    margin: 0;
}

#apple-list ul.holder li.bit-input input.smallinput {
    width: 5px;
}

ul.holder li.bit-hover {
    background: #BBCEF1;
    border: 1px solid #6D95E0;
}

ul.holder li.bit-box-focus {
    border-color: #598BEC;
    background: #598BEC;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.holder li.bit-box a.closebutton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    top: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    font-size: 1px;
    background: url('close.gif');
}

ul.holder li.bit-box a.closebutton:hover {
    background-position: 7px;
}

ul.holder li.bit-box-focus a.closebutton, ul.holder li.bit-box-focus a.closebutton:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}

/* Autocompleter */

#facebook-auto {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 512px;
    background: #eee;
}

#facebook-auto .default {
    padding: 5px 7px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px;
}

#facebook-auto ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#facebook-auto ul li {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px;
    font: 11px "Lucida Grande", "Verdana";
}

#facebook-auto ul li em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    background: #ccc;
}

#facebook-auto ul li.auto-focus {
    background: #4173CC;
    color: #fff;
}

#facebook-auto ul li.auto-focus em {
    background: none;
}

#demo ul.holder li.bit-input input {
    padding: 2px 0 1px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

#add a {
    color: #666;
}

#add-test {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 2px;
}

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>TextboxList + Autocomplete demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/test.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Test Stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/mootools-beta-1.2b1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!--<script src="textboxlist.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/textboxlist.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body id="test">
    <h1>TextboxList + Autocomplete Demo</h1>
    <p><a href="http://devthought.com/textboxlist-meets-autocompletion/">See article page</a>, <a href="http://devthought.com/textboxlist-fancy-facebook-like-dynamic-inputs/">Go to TextboxList article</a></p>

    <form action="test_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <ol>
            <li class="input-text">
                <label>Simple input</label>
                <input type="text" name="testinput" value="" id="testinput" />
            </li>

            <li id="facebook-list" class="input-text">
                <label>FacebookList input</label>
                <input type="text" value="" id="facebook-demo" />
                <div id="facebook-auto">
                    <div class="default">Type the name of an argentine writer you like</div>
                    <ul class="feed">
                        <li>Jorge Luis Borges</li>
                        <li>Julio Cortazar</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- These two writers will be added when the control is loaded -->
            </li>
        </ol>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is still. Do you see that problem __[here](http://devthought.com/wp-content/articles/autocompletelist/test.html)__ ? You posted a lot of CSS/code, can you make a jsFiddle with this?

Comment: that's 6 yrs old now. ` arguments.callee.parent()` - this is mootools 0.9 code. words like 'unsupported' (Guillermo Rauch has long since moved to nodejs dev, he wrote socket.io), 'abandonware' and 'good luck' spring to mind. it's a 30 min refactor to fix to latest mootools so it works fine.

Comment: oh and, because I needed this func, I wrote http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootagify a while ago. also warning that I no longer support it but it should work with 1.4.5 and all browsers. it has a `stupid` dependency on two bits from mootools-more, which need deprecating and it's good to go (element.shortcuts for .hide() and `.isVisible()` and Fx.Scroll, which i can't even remember using...).